# Better practice to show timestamp in android app

Tags: android, datetime, timestamp

I am creating an android application in which I am showing some tweets sent by server. I have confusion about how to go with showing timestamp with each tweet (like I want to show "1 hr ago" - time elapsed). I will list out my options:

1. I get GMT timestamp from server, I process it and get timestamp in user's timezone and then compare it with system current timestamp and show their difference. (Problem: I can't rely on device time as it will not be accurate. It can be earlier than server timestamp so their comparison would give me negative answer.)
2. Server can send me seconds elapsed from that tweet's origin and I can process that on android side and show. (Problem: If I cache this data and show it to user later in offline mode, this timestamp will remain same.)

Which will be the best approach to go about this? Also, how other giant companies manage this?

Answer (score 0):

use the **UTC Timezone for everything**, just when *displaying* it to the User, format it to his Timezone. When the user enters a date, write it as UTC formatted DateTime to your server.

If you cannot rely on the users DateTime, you will have to rely on your servers in any case.